# Weird error in BigQuery

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I trying to execute query directly from web console https://bigquery.cloud.google.com

One time query executed and I got result another time I got the error on the same query:

**Error: TABLE_QUERY expressions cannot query BigQuery tables.**

I also tried with different query option "Use Cached Results", "Interactive" and "Batch" behaviour the same.

Why it could happens?

Answer (score 2):

TABLE_QUERY filters are intended to query *only* metadata. For a brief period of time, it was possible to query table data in your TABLE_QUERY filter; we recently closed this loophole.

We're in the process of adding a whitelist for customers who are negatively impacted by this; the whitelist will allow them to query data within the same dataset in their TABLE_QUERY expression, until they can update their queries.

Note that you can still use `__TABLE_SUMMARY__` within the `TABLE_QUERY` experssion if you want to find the max table id, for example. For example:

```
SELECT foo 
FROM  TABLE_QUERY(my_dataset, 
  'table_id IN (SELECT MAX(table_id) 
   FROM my_dataset.__TABLES_SUMMARY__ 
   WHERE table_id CONTAINS "my_prefix")')
LIMIT 1
```

If this doesn't work for you, or you want your project to be whitelisted, please contact tigani@google.com.

Comment: can you please share some references regarding what is allowed and what not within table_query. I use subqueries that refer to other tables data within the table_query functions. Is this allowed?

Comment: I have opened a follow-up question asking how to work without this useful functionality: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36673468/error-table-query-expressions-cannot-query-bigquery-tables

Comment: The problem is that a) the functionality was very useful and b) I don't know of any valid workaround or alternative functionally that can be employed. Why are you considering this a bug rather than a useful hack?

Comment: This unintentional hack was able to bypass both billing and access control restrictions. We've gone through our logs and made sure no one used this inappropriately, but this is why we were so eager to fix it.