# Can you create a BigQuery UDF that generates lists of tables, instead of operating on rows?

Tags: function, google-bigquery, udf

I'm looking at the user-defined function docs for BigQuery, but I need to define a function to simplify the process of querying multiple tables. I have people who have to do stuff like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([SomeDataSet.SomeTableName_],DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),-2,'DAY'),DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),-1,'DAY'))) where magical_rainbows = 7;
```

Nobody is going to remember all of that, and they'll end up copy-pasting it in from some source, over and over. No big deal, except people are lazy and will inevitably develop the habit of setting that date range to be all-inclusive and run my bill through the roof.

I'd rather use a UDF to get all of that down to something they can remember - and type quickly:

```
SELECT * FROM da_tables([SomeDataSet.SomeTableName_], -2, -1) where .....
```

Everything I see in UDF, however, is about table schema production, and there doesn't appear to be a way for me to solve this headache.

Comment: If you ask "how can you make it easy to query over the last 3 days of tables to avoid all the cut-and-paste", I would suggest creating a view that embedded all your TABLE_DATE_RANGE() computations.

Comment: Regarding the concern of "run my bill through the roof", take a look at "Controlling query costs using BigQuery custom quotas" at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/cost-controls

Comment: it could have been done easily using table_query() and reference table containing the "business dates" metadata... as it was removed, please vote up for getting the functionality back... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36673468/error-table-query-expressions-cannot-query-bigquery-tables

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion--it seems like a useful feature to support functions that operate on tables in this way. I filed https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=535 in the BigQuery issue tracker.

Comment: To close the loop, we now support SQL UDFs that operate on structs (e.g. row types) so it's possible to express this sort of transformation with a function. I marked the corresponding feature request as fixed: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=535.

Answer (score 1):

Current implementation of BigQuery UDF does not provide this type of feature

Meantime  - on optimistic note:
Check `Big Data and Analytics` section in this blog [Google takes Cloud Machine Learning service mainstream](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/03/Google-takes-Cloud-Machine-Learning-service-mainstream.html). Specifically check out `Automatic Table Partitions` bullet!

In addition  - you can check [timePartitioning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#timePartitioning) experimental property in Table's Resource, which tells me that there is a progress in this direction :o)